# Subset Sum using recursive

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-tree, subset, backtracking

My Input is:

```
W[10] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 19, 22, 36, 63}
X[10] = {0};
M = 79;
```

I called the function by:

```
findSolution(0,0,177); <br>
```

Note: 177 is sum of all the elements inside W array.

```
void findSolution(int s, int k, int r) {
    cout << "fn(" << s << " , " << k << ", " << r << " )" << endl;
    X[k] = 1;
    if (s + W[k] == M){
        printArr(X);
    }
    else if (s + W[k] + W[k + 1] <= M) {
        return findSolution(s + W[k], k + 1, r - W[k]);
    }

    if ((s + r - W[k] >= M) && (s + W[k + 1]) <= M){
        X[k] = 0;
        return findSolution(s, k + 1, r - W[k]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
fn(0 , 0, 177 )
fn(1 , 1, 176 )
fn(4 , 2, 173 )
fn(9 , 3, 168 )
fn(16 , 4, 161 )
fn(25 , 5, 152 )
fn(37 , 6, 140 )
fn(56 , 7, 121 )
```

The output given above is to track the function calls. The output ends here and doesn't go forward. What is wrong with my code. I am trying to print a subset which gives a desired sum = 79. The recursive call doesn't return back.

Comment: What *should* the output be?  Or could you at least describe what this is supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your solution is that it uses a [greedy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) strategy (i.e. it does not "backtrack" after finding a suitable candidate).

Your algorithm checks for three conditions:

- You found a solution,
- A solution is possible if you *add* `k`-th element to the subset, or
- A solution is possible if you *replace* `k-1`-st element with `k`-th.

This strategy does not exhaust all possibilities: for instance, it may not be possible to replace `k`-th element with `k+1`-st, but it may be possible to replace several elements ahead of `k`-th with `k+1`-st and obtain a solution. Your strategy is greedy, because when it discovers that an element could be added to a set (i.e. `s + W[k] + W[k + 1] <= M`) it takes that path, and never looks back (i.e. returns from that branch).

You can fix this by restructuring your code as follows:

- Make your function return `true` when a solution is found, and `false` otherwise.
- Keep your base case `if (s + W[k] == M)`, and add a `return true` when a solution is found.
- Check if it is possible to add `k`-th element to the set. If it is possible, add it, and try for the partial sum of `s + W[k]`
- Check the return of the recursive invocation. If it is `true`, return `true`.
- Otherwise, remove `k`-th element from the set, and make a second recursive invocation without the `k`-th element in the mix. Use the same partial sum of `s`.
- Return the value of the last recursive invocation to the caller.

Now your algorithm is exhaustive, because for each element the algorithm tries to find a partial sum both when the element is part of the solution, and when the element is not part of the solution (i.e. O(2<sup>n</sup>) checks in all).

Answer (score 0):

The recursive call *is* returning back; it is just doing so before you found a solution.  This can happen if the last `if` is reached but fails.  (Note that what looks like your base case, when you call `printArr`, does *not* necessarily stop the recursion.)

Answer (score 0):

//code in c++ for return subset sum to k using recursion

int subsetSumToK(int input[], int n, int output[][50], int k) {

//as we are decreasing the value of k in int count1 recursive call, at a time value of k will be zero ,positive value and negative value also, so we will return only those subsets where the value of k is zero when the size of input array will become zero else we just return 0. In recursive calls we use two recursive calls, in first we are including the element, so as we including the element so now we have to find the value k - input[0](that included element) and store that element in o1 output array and in second recursive call as we are not including the element so just directily pass the call by input+1 and size-1 with o2 output array and the same value k.

```
if(n == 0){       //base case
    if(k==0){   
        output[0][0] = 0;
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}

int o1[1000][50]; //to store the output individually of two recusive calls    
int o2[1000][50];

int count1 = subsetSumToK(input+1,n-1,o1,k-input[0]);     //recursive calls
int count2 = subsetSumToK(input+1,n-1,o2,k);

for(int i=0;i<count1;i++){           //small calulations
    for(int j=1;j<=o1[i][0];j++){
        output[i][j+1] = o1[i][j];
    }
    output[i][0] = o1[i][0] +1;
    output[i][1] = input[0];
}

for(int i=0 ; i<count2 ; i++){
    for(int j=0 ; j<=o2[i][0] ; j++){
        output[i + count1][j] = o2[i][j];
    }
}

return count1 + count2;
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).